# Weird Sharepoint 2010 permissions errors

Tags: permissions

I went to the U.I and set a group of users to have limited access and read access and tried go to my home page of my site.

I get an access denied error and have no clue why. I found that I must give these  users at least contributor status before it will let them go to the home page. I find that extremely weird as that is too high of a level for these uses.

I just want these users to look around not add, edit and delete.

I really have no code I can post as I said I set this groups permissions through the sharepoint U.I.

Comment: How does this manifest itself? Do you get a page saying user dont have access, login as another user, or you get a windows login box or do you get an IIS access denied page?

Comment: The first way. I get a page saying users don't have access, login as another user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will often manifest itself when using publishing pages or any sort of library with major/minor versioning. If that is the case, be sure to publish at least 1 major version (i.e. 1.0) so that those users with read permissions will have the ability to view a page (as long as they have access to the library containing the page).

Comment: So your saying that maybe on my home page I have some library that was not published and this could be causing the problem

Comment: I would check and verify the page itself is published.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if any of the permissions for objects on the Home Page are conflicting due to disinheritance. This would include any script files, CSS files, etc., which may not be obvious to you if you weren't the implementer. Read permissions ought to be enough to let people, well, read.

You can't give someone Limited Access manually. That is a sort of "passthrough" permission, indicating that the user has permissions on a child object, but not the current object.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is a (3rd party?) web part on the home page is doing or accessing something that the logged in user does not have permission for.